# Correct way of calling a function in Julia

Tags: function, dataframe, julia

I am executing this line to call the function with a dataframe as variable, but it only gives me a λ value.

```
tool = DataFrame()
function algo(input_dataframe, tool, a=30, b=40, flag=false, sum, mean)
          #body of the function
          return probabsum, probabmedian
end
result = df -> algo(dataframe1, tool; a=1, b=2, flag=false, sum, mean)
```

Here dataframe1 is a variable which should take df as an input to execute the function.

Please suggest is it the correct way to call a function?

Comment: Please provide a MWE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Which function do you want to execute? A variable cannot take an input, so it's unclear what that means. And `function` is a reserved language keyword, so this does not make sense to me.

Comment: Apologies,
I created a function to measure to carry out mathematics, i have edited the code with more details of my problem. Here i was trying to pass df to the input_dataframe, and req_df dataframe is already declared globally. Here i am not sure how can i call this function with df as input dataframe. Hence, i am seeking the correct syntax which can execute the function. 

Hopefully, this provides more clarity on my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = df -> algo(dataframe1, tool; a=1, b=2, flag=false, sum, mean)
```

This creates an anonymous function and binds it to the name "result", without using your input parameter "df" at all.

I am not sure about your intention, either call

```
result = algo(dataframe1, tool; a=1, b=2, flag=false, sum, mean)
```

for direct execution of your function with existing "dataframe1", or create an anonymous function with

```
calc_result = df -> algo(df, tool; a=1, b=2, flag=false, sum, mean)
result = calc_result(dataframe1) # calculate result
```